# Search spelling mistakes in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am working on web application, but while working I found there are lots of spelling mistakes. Is there any plugin in Eclipse using which we can search the spelling mistakes in existing code?

Comment: use ctrl-f to search for words...

Comment: @Rob1NN i want to search spelling mistakes made while writing code. i know. using ctrl+ f we can find the word in current file

Comment: there's a ctrl-f mode that searches the entire project directory

Answer (score 0):

The best I found that I can do in Eclipse is file-wide search:

Go to `Window.Preferences.General.Editors."Text Editors".Annotations."Spelling Errors"`
and enable `"Include in next/previous navigation"`.
Then `Ctrl+(comma)` and `Ctrl+(period)` will jump to the previous/next spelling mistake in the current file.

Optionally, enable `"Vertical ruler"` and/or `"Overview ruler"` to give visual feedback on spelling mistakes, similarly to warnings and errors.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to Window->Preferences->Editors[+]->Text Editors[+]->Spelling and check Enable Spelling.

Also, for spell checking to work, it is currently mandatory for you to provide a dictionary. Thankfully it's not that hard to find a word-list Eclipse can use. Eclipse supports a fairly standard one-word-per-line format for the 'dictionary' file, so we just have to find one of those. You can get one of those here:
[here](http://www.javalobby.org/images/postings/rj/eclipse_spelling/dictionary.txt)

Comment: I think you did not understand the Question. i want to search the spelling mistakes in Project. there are multiple files in project and i can not go each file and check it.